# Не пойму как правильно через метод toString вывести инфу про машину

Tags: javascript, ооп

```js
 class Car {
    constructor ( clasAouto, engine, driver, marka ) {
        this.clasAouto = clasAouto;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.marka = marka;
    }
    start(start) {
        document.write(`${start} поехали`)
    }
    stop(stop) {
        document.write(`${stop} стоять`)
    }
    turnRight(right) {
        document.write(`${right} право`)
    }
    turnLeft(left) {
        document.write(`${left} лево`)
    }
    toString(title) {
        document.write( title + " " + this.clasAouto + " " + this.engine + " " + this.driver + " " + this.marka );
    }
}
let car = new Car()
document.writeln(car.toString("Mers"))
```

> `Цитата`

Comment: Вы когда создаете экземпляр класс Car, не передаете данные в конструктор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот одна из реализаций класса с методами

```js
class Car {
  constructor ( clasAouto, engine, driver, marka ) {
    this.clasAouto = clasAouto;
    this.engine = engine;
    this.driver = driver;
    this.marka = marka;
  }
  start(command) {
    console.log(`${this.driver} поехал на ${this.marka} - по команде ${command}` )
  }
  stop(command) {
    console.log(`${this.driver} стоять на ${this.marka} - по команде ${command}` )
  }
  turnRight(command) {
    console.log(`${this.driver} повернул на право - по команде ${command}` )
  }
  turnLeft(command) {
    console.log(`${this.driver} повернул на лево - по команде ${command}` )
  }
  toString(command) {
    console.log(`У ${this.driver} есть ${this.clasAouto} ${this.marka} с двигателем ${this.engine} - Такой ответ на вопрос '${command}'`)
  }
}
let car = new Car('Седан', 'Бензин', 'Петя', 'Ford');
car.start('Гони');
car.turnRight('На лево');
car.turnLeft('Да на другое лево');
car.stop('Ой, всё, тормози!');
car.toString('Кто тебе права дал?');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое